# Deleted firestore data not reduce Stored Data Quota

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, quota

Why when I deleted data from firestore, not reduce Firestore Stored Data Quota, I've tried to delete all data from CLI with this commad :

```
>firebase firestore:delete --all-collections     
? You are about to delete YOUR ENTIRE DATABASE. Are you sure? Yes 
Deleting the following collections: restaurants                   
Deleted 94 docs (26 docs/s)
```

Is there anything I miss regarding this quota problem?

Answer (score 1):

After a few days I deleted all the data, today I see the quota has been reduced (reset to 0 GB), I'm not sure what I've missed, because there is no cycle information for the firestore stored data quota, considering that the firestore is still beta, I hope to get information related to the day later on

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref('mynode/mychildnode').remove();
```

Comment: I've tried to delete subcollection manualy from firebase console, I don't see a reduced quota

Comment: Well have you check it is being deleted 

1) you may have an incorrect path 
2) You may have a permissions/rules issue stopping the writing/removal of data

Comment: @PHILLBOOTH your answer is about the Firebase Realtime Database, while Toing is asking about Cloud Firestore. While both are part of Firebase, they are completely separate databases with their own storage.

Comment: @PHILLBOOTH I looked at the firebase console and made sure there were no more visible data (all erased), but the quota wasn't reduced at all,

thanks to FrankvanPuffelen for the clarification, I did ask about firestore, not the firebase realtime database